# product->save takes about 3-4 seconds per simple product for a simple QTY change

Tags: magento2

I made a simple script which sets the QTY of certain products based on a CSV.

It all works perfectly excepting the fact that it takes around 3 seconds for each product to be saved.

What could I do to optimize it's saving speed?

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

include('../app/bootstrap.php');
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$_objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('adminhtml');

//list of products to check


$csvFile = file('data.csv');
$data = [];
$i=0;
foreach ($csvFile as $line) {
    $i++;
    $products[str_getcsv($line,';')[1]] = str_getcsv($line,';')[3];
}

echo sprintf('Loaded stock for '.$i.' products'."\n");




echo "Starting...\n";


$_zeroQtyProducts = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection')->addAttributeToFilter('name', array('like' => '%special%'));
$_stockState = $_objectManager->get('\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface');
$_stockRegistry = $_objectManager->get('\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface');

//if any products found
if ($_zeroQtyProducts) {
    echo sprintf("Found %s product(s)\n", count($_zeroQtyProducts));

    foreach ($_zeroQtyProducts as $_product) {
        $_stock = $_stockState->getStockQty($_product->getId(), $_product->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
        $_sku = $_product->getSku();
        $prodname=$special_var;

                if (isset($products[$prodname])) {
                    $_stockItem = $_stockRegistry->getStockItem($_product->getId());
                    $_stockItem->setData('is_in_stock', 1); //set updated data as your requirement
                    $_stockItem->setData('qty', $products[$prodname]); //set updated quantity
                    $_stockItem->save(); //save stock of item
                    $_product->save();
                    echo sprintf("Product qty updated to: %s for ".$_sku."\n", $products[$prodname]);
                } else {
                    echo sprintf('Can\'t find stock for product ' . $prodname . '  --  ' . $_sku."\n");
                }

            }
        }
    
    }

} else {
    echo sprintf("0 Products found with provided SKU's.\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn off stock index on save - set it on schedule and call it once either as part of your process above or configure stock index to run on schedule using magento indexer - but delay it until after your process is done.

Last time I checked there is a stock index and an inventory MSI index. You may need to run both.

Comment: I commented out $product->save() leaving only  $_stockItem->save(); and its going way faster. You think this would work out?

Answer (score 0):

As you are updating only quantity so
$_stockItem->save(); //save stock of item

$_product->save();  ?? this is needed if you want to update other product details.